# Pass information between independently running Powershell scrips

Tags: powershell, runspace

**Sorry for being wage before**. I'll try again:

The circumstances are too complicated to explain, but basically the problem is:

- **how to pass a string (max 20 chars) from one script, to another script** running on the same machine.
- the two scripts are running continuously in the background, on the **same machine**, under the **same user context**,
  but **can not be combined**.
- I **can not dot-source** one script in the other.

I have done it by having one script create a file with the string in it, in a directory monitored by the other script. So when it appears, the other script reads the information.
It works, but it feels "dirty". :)

I was wondering if there is a "**best practice**"-way to pass information between scripts or at least a **more elegant** way.

Thanks.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, instead of what you perceive as the solution. Why would it matter if the second script fails during initialization, but not if it fails afterwards? Why does the first script need to terminate while the second continues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways for enabling two continuously running processes on the same host to communicate with each other, for instance named pipes:

```bsh
# named pipe - server
$name = 'foo'
$namedPipe = New-Object IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream($name, 'Out')
$namedPipe.WaitForConnection()

$script:writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter($namedPipe)
$writer.AutoFlush = $true
$writer.WriteLine('something')
$writer.Dispose()

$namedPipe.Dispose()
```

```bsh
# named pipe - client
$name = 'foo'
$namedPipe = New-Object IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream('.', $name, 'In')
$namedPipe.Connect()

$script:reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($namedPipe)
$reader.ReadLine()
$reader.Dispose()

$namedPipe.Dispose()
```

or TCP sockets:

```bsh
# TCP socket - server
$addr = [ipaddress]'127.0.0.1'
$port = 1234

$endpoint = New-Object Net.IPEndPoint ($addr, $port)
$server = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpListener $endpoint
$server.Start()
$cn = $server.AcceptTcpClient()

$stream = $cn.GetStream()
$writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter($stream)
$writer.WriteLine('something')
$writer.Dispose()

$server.Stop()
```

```bsh
# TCP socket - client
$server = '127.0.0.1'
$port   = 1234

$client = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
$client.Connect($server, $port)
$stream = $client.GetStream()

$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($stream)
$reader.ReadLine()
$reader.Dispose()

$client.Dispose()
```

Comment: At this point, we're almost exclusively using .NET which begs the question: are we really using powershell at this point? The answer of course is yes, but the grand scope of things makes me chuckle.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution would be to make the second script a function, then dot source it and just capture the return value into a variable.

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible otherwise, you could try `$global:variableName` or possibly run something as a job. If none of that works you could make the second script store the result in a file then access that file from the first script.

Comment: Global variables set in one runspace are not readable in another runspace. Dot sourcing is not possible in this case unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

While your question is not very clear, i'll try to answer it.

It seems like you want to continue processing on your first script while your second script is doing (something).

You can put a specific operation in a Job (sort of like a thread) and receive it later with a `while ($true)` loop specifying conditions that meet your needs then break out of the loop after receiving the results from that Job, or thread.

Take a look at `Get-Help | Start-Job` for more info on that, or try to hit up google.

You can also import user-defined functions from another script by doing an `import-module '.\pathtoscriptmodule.psm1'` or just `.\Pathtoscriptdefiningfunctions.ps1` to import functions you want to use from an outside script file.

Examples of using Start job..

```
$scriptblock = {
param($myParam); 
    # My commands here
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -args $myParamsIWantToPassToScriptblock

While ($true){
    # To view status of that background job
    Get-Job *
    # Add your logic for fulfilling your conditons here, then
    # break; <<uncomment to break out of loop
    if (conditions met)
    {
        break;
    }
}

# Gets the output from that job. -Keep keeps the output in memory
# if you want to call it multiple times
Receive-Job * -Keep
```

Comment: I reworded the question to (hopefully) explain it better. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using runspaces.

http://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/19/sharing-variables-and-live-objects-between-powershell-runspaces/